# Command line program keep logging output into seperate window

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm using a bat file to run some ADB command. This is the content:

```
cd C:\AutoToolApx\AutoOffer\AutoOffer\bin\Debug
adb connect localhost:5555
adb -s localhost:5555 shell pm clear com.google.android.gms
adb -s localhost:5555 shell "su -c 'mount -o remount,rw none /sdcard;'
adb -s localhost:5555 push "C:\AutoToolApx\AutoOffer\AutoOffer\bin\Debug\data\bsinfor.txt" "/sdcard/bsinfor.txt"
adb -s localhost:5555 shell "su -c 'mount -o remount,rw none /data;busybox cp /sdcard/bsinfor.txt /data/bsinfor.txt;chmod 777 /data/bsinfor.txt;'"
exit
```

It used to print the output in the same window, as I expect. Now it prints the respond output in separated windows for each line of command:

[image]

This makes my program cannot work in the way I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your batch file, and surround each command with the following code:

```
cmd /k "..."
```

where ... is replaced with your command. For example:

```
cmd /k "adb connect localhost:5555"
```

cmd /k will execute this command and reuse the window.

Comment: It didn't work for me. New windows still be opened.